# Mismatch between Google OAuth 2.0 Client IDs JSON structure and Go struct

Tags: json, go, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0

I recently downloaded the OAuth 2.0 Client IDs(desktop app) from the Google Cloud Console and observed a discrepancy between the JSON structure and the expected Go struct in packages like ConfigFromJSON.

Here's the JSON structure I received:

```
{
  "WCc": {
    "client_id": "*****apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "project_id": "persuasive",
    "Anc": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "hVc": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "znc": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "s2a": "GOCSPX-*******",
    "oNc": ["http://localhost"]
  }
}
```

Traditionally, libraries and packages have used structures like:

```
type cred struct {
    ClientID     string   `json:"client_id"`
    ClientSecret string   `json:"client_secret"`
    RedirectURIs []string `json:"redirect_uris"`
    AuthURI      string   `json:"auth_uri"`
    TokenURI     string   `json:"token_uri"`
}
```

This mismatch is causing some decoding issues when attempting to use utilities such as ConfigFromJSON.

Has anyone else faced this change in the JSON structure from the Google Cloud Console? How should I adjust my Go struct to properly decode this format? Moreover, is there an updated version or alternative to ConfigFromJSON that accommodates this new structure?

Thank you for any insights or help!

In an attempt to resolve the issue, I tried regenerating the OAuth 2.0 Client IDs from the Google Cloud Console, hoping it might give me the traditional format I was familiar with.
I was expecting to get the JSON structure matching the commonly used Go struct, especially the one compatible with the `ConfigFromJSON` function. However, even after regenerating the IDs, the format remained as the one shown above.

Comment: I do not recognize the received JSON from Google. Are you using a single sign-on service? Add more details to your post.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
SSO: No. I'm directly interfacing with Google's OAuth 2.0 service for authentication in my application. 
Steps I've Taken:
1. went to the Google Cloud Console.
2. navigated to the 'Credentials' section under 'API & Services'.
3. created OAuth 2.0 Client IDs for a desktop app.
4. After configuring the OAuth consent screen, I downloaded the JSON credentials, which resulted in the aforementioned structure.

Comment: I just redownloaded my client secrets and I get the same as your first example. Something has changed. Here is an example documentation link for what the old format is: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_client_secrets I am not aware of a new document link yet.

Comment: This is a Google bug that is now fixed. Please re-download the secrets.